# MySQL: Select query execution and result fetch time increases with number of connections

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-performance, query-performance

My server application makes multiple connections to MySQL through separate threads. Each connection fires a `SELECT` query and fetches result which the application then caters back to its connected users.

I am using InnoDB. To my surprise I found it a very weird that if I increase number of connections to MySQL, query performance deteriorates and result fetch time also increases. Below is a table showing same.

This data is produced when I had 3333 records in MySQL table and the `SELECT` query based on random parameters given to it fetches around 450 records out of them. Each record has around 10 fields and all of them together contains 1.2 KB of data. (Thus, single `SELECT` query fetches 1.2 * 450 = 540 KB data in total)

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════════╦══════════════╗
║ Number of ║Query execution║ Result fetch ║
║connections║  time range   ║  time range  ║
║ to MySQL  ║ (in seconds)  ║ (in seconds) ║ 
╠═══════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║     1     ║ 0.02 to 0.06  ║ 0.03 to 0.18 ║
║     7     ║ 0.23 to 0.64  ║ 0.54 to 0.74 ║
║    17     ║ 0.32 to 1.71  ║ 0.53 to 1.18 ║
║    37     ║ 0.37 to 2.01  ║ 0.70 to 1.70 ║
║   117     ║ 1.13 to 3.29  ║ 2.48 to 3.25 ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════════╩══════════════╝
```

What I don't understand here is why does MySQL take more time when number of connections to it are increased? Especially when there are no updates being made to the table, MySQL should process `SELECT` request from each connection in separate thread. Thus concurrent processing of query. Hence, ideally there shouldn't be significant degrade in performance and fetch.

I won't mind to have single connection to DB but catch is that my server performance significantly degrades with it. Thousands of users (connected to my server) will have to wait for that single thread for their turn to come.

After going through some related questions on SO I tried increasing 
`innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 1 GB with no luck.

Here are my all InnoDB parameters:

```
innodb_adaptive_flushing    ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm    10
innodb_adaptive_hash_index  ON
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay 150000
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size 2097152
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval   5
innodb_api_disable_rowlock  OFF
innodb_api_enable_binlog    OFF
innodb_api_enable_mdl   OFF
innodb_api_trx_level    0
innodb_autoextend_increment 64
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode    1
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_filename ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    8
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort   OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size 1073741824
innodb_change_buffer_max_size   25
innodb_change_buffering all
innodb_checksum_algorithm   crc32
innodb_checksums    ON
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled    OFF
innodb_commit_concurrency   0
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct    5
innodb_compression_level    6
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max  50
innodb_concurrency_tickets  5000
innodb_data_file_path   ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir    
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache  OFF
innodb_doublewrite  ON
innodb_fast_shutdown    1
innodb_file_format  Antelope
innodb_file_format_check    ON
innodb_file_format_max  Antelope
innodb_file_per_table   ON
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  2
innodb_flush_method normal
innodb_flush_neighbors  1
innodb_flushing_avg_loops   30
innodb_force_load_corrupted OFF
innodb_force_recovery   0
innodb_ft_aux_table 
innodb_ft_cache_size    8000000
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print OFF
innodb_ft_enable_stopword   ON
innodb_ft_max_token_size    84
innodb_ft_min_token_size    3
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize 2000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit    2000000000
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table 
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree   2
innodb_ft_total_cache_size  640000000
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table   
innodb_io_capacity  200
innodb_io_capacity_max  2000
innodb_large_prefix OFF
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  OFF
innodb_log_buffer_size  268435456
innodb_log_compressed_pages ON
innodb_log_file_size    262144000
innodb_log_files_in_group   2
innodb_log_group_home_dir   .\
innodb_lru_scan_depth   1024
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct  75
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm  0
innodb_max_purge_lag    0
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay  0
innodb_mirrored_log_groups  1
innodb_monitor_disable  
innodb_monitor_enable   
innodb_monitor_reset    
innodb_monitor_reset_all    
innodb_old_blocks_pct   37
innodb_old_blocks_time  1000
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size    134217728
innodb_open_files   300
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only   OFF
innodb_page_size    16384
innodb_print_all_deadlocks  OFF
innodb_purge_batch_size 300
innodb_purge_threads    1
innodb_random_read_ahead    OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold 56
innodb_read_io_threads  64
innodb_read_only    OFF
innodb_replication_delay    0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF
innodb_rollback_segments    128
innodb_sort_buffer_size 1048576
innodb_spin_wait_delay  6
innodb_stats_auto_recalc    ON
innodb_stats_method nulls_equal
innodb_stats_on_metadata    OFF
innodb_stats_persistent ON
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages    20
innodb_stats_sample_pages   8
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages 8
innodb_status_output    OFF
innodb_status_output_locks  OFF
innodb_strict_mode  OFF
innodb_support_xa   ON
innodb_sync_array_size  1
innodb_sync_spin_loops  30
innodb_table_locks  ON
innodb_thread_concurrency   8
innodb_thread_sleep_delay   0
innodb_undo_directory   .
innodb_undo_logs    128
innodb_undo_tablespaces 0
innodb_use_native_aio   OFF
innodb_use_sys_malloc   ON
innodb_version  5.6.28
innodb_write_io_threads 16
```

Can someone please throw light? This is bugging me for really long time.

(*Note:* I haven't mentioned actual query in this question because query is little complicated and this question is not about that query. But it's about performance degradation with increasing connections when query is same)

**UPDATE 1**

Here is `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output for my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `profiles` (
  `SRNO` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `HANDLE_FIRST` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `HANDLE_SECOND` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `USERID` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `UNIQUESTRING` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `CLIENT_VERSION` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ISCONNECTED` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `ISPROFILEPRESENT` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `USERNAME` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `GENDER` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DND` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PROFILE_URL` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SRNO`),
  UNIQUE KEY `USERID` (`USERID`),
  KEY `USERID_INDEX` (`USERID`),
  KEY `UNIQUESTRING_INDEX` (`UNIQUESTRING`),
  KEY `ISCONNECTED_INDEX` (`ISCONNECTED`),
  KEY `ISPROFILEPRESENT_INDEX` (`ISPROFILEPRESENT`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9250 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `blockers` (
  `BLOCKER_PROFILE_SRNO` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `BLOCKED_PROFILE_SRNO` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `BLOCKER_PROFILE_SRNO` (`BLOCKER_PROFILE_SRNO`,`BLOCKED_PROFILE_SRNO`),
  KEY `BLOCKER_PROFILE_SRNO_INDEX` (`BLOCKER_PROFILE_SRNO`),
  KEY `BLOCKED_PROFILE_SRNO_INDEX` (`BLOCKED_PROFILE_SRNO`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_BlockedIndex` FOREIGN KEY (`BLOCKED_PROFILE_SRNO`) REFERENCES `profiles` (`SRNO`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_BlockerIndex` FOREIGN KEY (`BLOCKER_PROFILE_SRNO`) REFERENCES `profiles` (`SRNO`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And here is the query I am running:

```
select  prfls.*
    from  profiles as prfls
    left outer join  blockers as blkr1 on blkr1.blocker_profile_srno = prfls.srno
      and  blkr1.blocked_profile_srno = 6443
    left outer join  blockers as blkr2 on blkr2.blocker_profile_srno = 6443
      and  blkr2.blocked_profile_srno = prfls.srno
    where  blkr1.blocker_profile_srno is null
      and  blkr2.blocker_profile_srno is null
      and  (      (prfls.uniquestring like 'phk5600dcc%')
              or  (prfls.uniquestring like 'phk5600dcf%')
           )
      and  prfls.isconnected=1
      and  prfls.isprofilepresent=1
    limit  450
```

This query is essentially a prepared statement where `blocked_profile_srno`, `blocker_profile_srno` and `uniquestring` parameters keep changing for each query. However `blocked_profile_srno` and `blocker_profile_srno` always remains equal (in above query their value is 6443). Table `blockers` is blank (I have it in place for future use but currently it has no data in it)

When 117 connections were simultaneously running queries, output of `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Threads_running';` was most of the time 1. However it sometimes went upto 27. At the same time, output of `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Max_used_connections';` was 130

**UPDATE 2**

I can gather from Rick James answer below that optimizing query reduces query execution time range. This time range still keeps increasing with number of connections but within acceptable range. This is why I've accepted the answer.

Comment: total number of executed queries per second differs for different number of connections? How many cores your cpu has?

Comment: What hardware are you running this on?

Comment: Well it's not high end hardware indeed. Double core CPU@3.00 GHz with 4 GB RAM and OS is Windows 8.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and a sample `SELECT`.  Usually the indexes and the query determine performance.

Comment: You say 117 connections, but were there 117 queries running simultaneously?  Show us `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Threads_running';` when the 117 were running and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Max_used_connections';`

Comment: @RickJames: Thanks for looking into it. I've updated the question with the information you've asked. Please have a look and advice me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably each connection is doing a full table scan of `profiles`.  Let's try to avoid that.  When there are dozens of queries hitting the same table, there are locks that cause InnoDB to "stumble over itself".  Either of these plans will both speed up the query and decrease the number of rows touched (hence decrease the locking).  The use of the suggested "composite" index will speed up the query.  But the `OR` gets in the way.  I see two tricks to still have an index look at `uniquestring`, but avoid some or all of the `OR`.

```
(      (prfls.uniquestring like 'phk5600dcc%')
   or  (prfls.uniquestring like 'phk5600dcf%')
)
```

`OR` is hard to optimize.

Add this:

```
INDEX(isconnected, isprofilepresent, uniquestring)
```

Then...

Plan A:

```
prfls.uniquestring         like 'phk5600dc%' AND  -- note common prefix
(      (prfls.uniquestring like 'phk5600dcc%')
   or  (prfls.uniquestring like 'phk5600dcf%')
)
```

This assumes you can construct that common prefix.

Plan B (turn `OR` into `UNION`):

```
( SELECT ...
    WHERE prfls.uniquestring like 'phk5600dcc%' AND ...
    LIMIT 450 )
UNION ALL    -- ? You may want DISTINCT, if there could be dups
( SELECT ...
    WHERE prfls.uniquestring like 'phk5600dcf%' AND ...  -- the only diff
    LIMIT 450 )
LIMIT 450   -- yes, again
```

Plan A (if practical) takes advantage of what *seems* to be a common starting value.  Plan B works regardless, but is probably a little slower, although still a lot faster than the original.

Other notes...

Indexes on flags (of which you have two) are almost never used.  `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` will probably show that neither was used.  Please provide the `EXPLAIN` for any `SELECT` that needs discussion.

A `UNIQUE KEY` is a `KEY`, so there is not need for the redundant index on `USERID`.

`limit 450` -- Which 450 do you want?  Without an `ORDER BY`, the query is allowed to give you *any* 450.  (Of course, perhaps that is fine.)  (And `ORDER BY` would probably slow down the query.)

My suggestions will not "solve" the problem, but they should increase the number of connections before the slow-down becomes noticeable.

Comment: Thanks for these valuable inputs. I'll optimize the query. But I just tried to run simple query `SELECT * FROM PROFILES WHERE SRNO > ? LIMIT 450` (with different `SRNO` from each connection) and this also showing same behaviour (i.e. with increasing number of connections query took longer to run). Now, this query also would do full table scan resulting in locks? I have in fact chosen InnoDB because I read it is best for concurrent query processing as it has ability to row level locking unlike full table locks in MyISAM. And I don't explicitly specify lock why InnoDB locks table?

Comment: OK, that's a better test case to chase.  Questions...  What is the setting of autocommit?  Is the `SELECT` part of `BEGIN...COMMIT`?  What does `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` say during such a slowdown?

Comment: autocommit was off. There is no particular time where all connections will slow down. I carried out an exercise. Fired 1000 SELECT queries by 100 connections simultaneously (so 10 by each), Some queries took 0.002 secs while some took 0.2 secs. Rest were in between this rage. There is no pattern as such I found. It's almost random. Instead of 100 connections, if I had 10 connections, this range would be something from 0.002 sec to 0.02 sec. **Range of inconsistency widens with number of connections**

Comment: Whie I carried out this exercise, in `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` under TRANSACTIONS there are repeating lines "MySQL thread id 5358, OS thread handle 0xdd0, query id 584867 localhost 127.0.0.1 dbuser cleaning up" and under FILE I/O ther are repeating lines "I/O thread 2 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)" and "I/O thread 81 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)" Other than this couldn't see any warning or error.

Comment: So, all 10 `SELECTs` were in the _same_ transaction?  I suggest that is not realistic.  Turn autocommit ON.

Comment: No. After each `select` I called commit before I fire next `select`. I just now tried turning autocommit on and in fact it widened the range from 0.002 to 4.0 seconds (which was previously 0.002 to 0.02. I guess it took that additional time to commit?)

Comment: If the "0.02" did not include the `COMMIT`, then you have the explanation.  So, the "4.0" makes your original question even more relevant.

Comment: Probably the answer is that the connections are stepping on each other by mostly (not always) fetching the _same_ rows (as part of 450 out of 3333).  Are 450 and 3333 "realistic"?  Or is this a fabricated benchmark?

Comment: It would be 450 in production but number of records can be anything large (3333 is for the sake of test harness as it could simulate only few thousands of users). What I am feeling from our discussion is, the range of inconsistency will be there (as opposite to what I was expecting, ideally, consistent performance of same queries across connections). All we can do is we can ***minimize*** the range by tuning our queries so that it touches minimum rows. That's only thing we can do probably.

Comment: Will the 'real' system often touch the _same_ rows?  (The overlap of multiple 450's is part of the problem.)

Comment: Yes it's quite possible that multiple DB connections (in *real* scenario) will try to access rows in common. And as long as its just select (and no update) I don't see any reason to loose concurrency.

Comment: Have you taken action on my comments on `OR`?  That should cut down on the number of rows actually touched.  (You are probable touching more than 450.)

Comment: Yes I am working on the same. It's little complicated (viz Plan A) because query could have as many as 90 `uniquestrings` to search for (that involves strings and their substrings and their substrings and so on). So it will become heavily composite clause to form. But yes, it will reduce number of rows scanned to large extent as you mentioned. So worth putting efforts. Will update you on findings. Many many thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that `AND (x OR y)` will not use an index, but `AND z` might.  That is, you can't take advantage of pulling out more than the common prefix for _all_ the strings.  That should be one simple pass.

Comment: And if the resulting common prefix is more than, say, 20% of the rows, the index still won't be used.  That is, there are cases where Plan A won't help.

Comment: Because this question was basically about MySQL performance wrt growing connections, I thought to pose another question pertaining specific to this query. Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34564825/mysql-optimized-query-to-find-matching-strings-from-set-of-strings I request you to advice me on it if possible.