# MySQL: Optimized query to find matching strings from set of strings

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, query-performance

I am having 10 sets of strings each set having 9 strings. Of this 10 sets, all strings in first set have length 10, those in second set have length 9 and so on. Finally, all strings in 10th set have length 1.

There is common prefix of (length-2) characters in each set. And the prefix length reduces by 1 in next set. Thus, first set has 8 characters in common, second has 7 and so on.

Here is what a sample of 10 sets look like:

```
pu3q0k0vwn
pu3q0k0vwp
pu3q0k0vwr
pu3q0k0vwq
pu3q0k0vwm
pu3q0k0vwj
pu3q0k0vtv
pu3q0k0vty
pu3q0k0vtz

pu3q0k0vw
pu3q0k0vy
pu3q0k0vz
pu3q0k0vx
pu3q0k0vr
pu3q0k0vq
pu3q0k0vm
pu3q0k0vt
pu3q0k0vv

pu3q0k0v
pu3q0k0y
pu3q0k1n
pu3q0k1j
pu3q0k1h
pu3q0k0u
pu3q0k0s
pu3q0k0t
pu3q0k0w

pu3q0k0
pu3q0k2
pu3q0k3
pu3q0k1
pu3q07c
pu3q07b
pu3q05z
pu3q0hp
pu3q0hr

pu3q0k
pu3q0m
pu3q0t
pu3q0s
pu3q0e
pu3q07
pu3q05
pu3q0h
pu3q0j

pu3q0
pu3q2
pu3q3
pu3q1
pu3mc
pu3mb
pu3jz
pu3np
pu3nr

pu3q
pu3r
pu3x
pu3w
pu3t
pu3m
pu3j
pu3n
pu3p

pu3
pu9
pud
pu6
pu4
pu1
pu0
pu2
pu8

pu
pv
0j
0h
05
pg
pe
ps
pt

p
r
2
0
b
z
y
n
q
```

**Requirement:**
I have a table PROFILES having columns SRNO (type bigint, primary key) and UNIQUESTRING (type char(10), unique key). I want to find 450 SRNOs for matching UNIQUESTRINGs from those 10 sets.

First find strings *like* in the first set. If we don't get enough results (ie. 450), find strings *like* in second set. If we still don't get enough results (450 minus *results of first set*) find strings *like* in third set. And so on.

**Existing Solution:**
I've written query something like:

```
select srno from  profiles
    where  ( (uniquestring like 'pu3q0k0vwn%')
              or  (uniquestring like 'pu3q0k0vwp%') -- all those above uniquestrings after this and finally the last one
              or  (uniquestring like 'n%')
              or  (uniquestring like 'q%')
           )
    limit  450
```

However, after getting feedback from Rick James in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34515133/1911652) I realized this is not optimized query as it touches lot many rows than it needs.
So I plan to rewrite the query like this:

```
(select srno from  profiles where uniquestring like 'pu3q0k0vwn%' LIMIT 450)
UNION DISTINCT
(select srno from  profiles where uniquestring like 'pu3q0k0vwp%' LIMIT 450); -- and more such clauses after this for each uniquestring
```

I like to know if there are any better solutions to do this.

Comment: Please clarify the numbers:  "10 sets of 9 string" sounds like 90 rows.  That is much less than 450.

Comment: Yes that's correct. 90 strings I am going to search and number of results limited to 450 (So query will have those 90 strings)

Comment: For example:  `(select SRNO from  profiles where UNIQUESTRING like 'pu3q0k0vwn%' LIMIT 450) UNION DISTINCT (select srno from  profiles where uniquestring like 'pu3q0k0vwp%' LIMIT 450) UNION DISTINCT`... it will repeat for 90 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE str   LIKE  'pu3q0k0vw%' AND -- the 10-char set
          str REGEXP '^pu3q0k0vw[nprqmj]'  -- the 9 next letters
    LIMIT ...
# then check for 450; if not enough, continue...
SELECT ...
    WHERE str   LIKE  'pu3q0k0vt%' AND -- the 10-char set
          str REGEXP '^pu3q0k0vt[vyz]'  -- the 9 next letters
    LIMIT 450
# then check for 450; if not enough, continue...
etc.
SELECT ...
    WHERE str   LIKE  'pu3q0k0v%' AND -- the 9-char set
          str REGEXP '^pu3q0k0v[wyzxrqmtv]'  -- the 9 next letters
    LIMIT ...
# check, etc; for a total of 10 SELECTs or 450 rows, whichever comes first.
```

This will be 10+ selects.  Each select will be somewhat optimized by first picking rows with a common prefix with LIKE, then it double checks with a REGEXP.

(If you don't like splitting the inconsistent `pu3q0k0vw` vs. `pu3q0k0vt`; we can discuss things further.)

You say "prefix"; I have coded the LIKE and REGEXP to assume arbitrary text *after* the prefix given.

`UNION` is not viable, since it will (I think) gather all the rows before picking 450.  Each `SELECT` will stop at the `LIMIT` *if* there is no `DISTINCT` `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY` that require gathering everything first.

`REGEXP` is not smart enough to avoid scanning the entire table; adding the `LIKE` avoids such (except when more than, say, 20% of the rows match the `LIKE`).

Comment: If we look at fourth set `pu3q0k0
pu3q0k2
pu3q0k3
pu3q0k1
pu3q07c
pu3q07b
pu3q05z
pu3q0hp
pu3q0hr` last two characters are differed (unlike last one in second set). How REGEX can be written for this? (So that I can always write single query per set)

Comment: Another issue I can see is, I have to compare results of `SELECT` with those of previous one, on my own, in order to ensure they are distinct. If that is the case then I need to gather as many results as possible instead of `LIMIT`ing them.

Comment: `str LIKE 'pu3q0%' AND str REGEXP '^pu3q0(k0|k2|k3|k1|7c|7b|5z|hp|hr)'`